# Editar itens html+php+jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

Tenho que editar uma série de registro, os mesmo estão listados em um table (veja):

[image: Table com os registros]

Este é o formulário da imagem a cima:

```
 <div class="control-group">
                <table class="table table-bordered ">
                    <thead>
                    <tr style="backgroud-color: #2D335B">
                        <th>Nome do Envolvido</th>
                        <th>RG</th>
                        <th>Envolvimento</th>
                        <th>Opções</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php if (!$envolvidos) { ?>
                        <td colspan="5">Ainda sem envolvidos</td>
                    <?php } else {
                        foreach ($envolvidos as $r) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="id_e" name="id_e"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>">
                                        <input class="span9" type="text" id="nome_e" name="nome_e"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('nome', $r->nome); ?>">
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <input class="span6" type="text" id="rg_e" name="rg_e"
                                               value="<?php echo set_value('rg', $r->rg); ?>">
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <select style="width: 120px" id="envolvimento_e" name="envolvimento_e"
                                                value="<?php echo set_value('envolvimento', $r->envolvimento); ?>">
                                            <option
                                                value="SOLICITANTE" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'SOLICITANTE') echo 'selected' ?>>
                                                Solicitante
                                            </option>
                                            <option
                                                value="AUTOR" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'AUTOR') echo 'selected' ?>>
                                                Autor
                                            </option>
                                            <option
                                                value="VITIMA" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'VITIMA') echo 'selected' ?>>
                                                Vítima
                                            </option>
                                            <option
                                                value="TESTEMUNHA" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'TESTEMUNHA') echo 'selected' ?>>
                                                Testemunha
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <button type="button" id="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Editar
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        <?php }
                    } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <thead>
                    <tr style="backgroud-color: #2D335B">
                        <th>Nome do Envolvido</th>
                        <th>RG</th>
                        <th>Envolvimento</th>
                        <th>Opções</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

E já tentei colocando cada `tr` dentro de um `form`, o problema que a edição só funciona para o primeiro item da `table` os demais não dispara o ajax que manda para o controler. Vejam o ajax:

```
jQuery('#enviar').click(function () {
        var id = $('#id_e').val();
        var nome = $('#nome_e').val();
        var rg = $('#rg_e').val();
        var envolvimento = $('#envolvimento_e').val();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/sbp/editarEnvolvido",
            {'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'rg': rg, 'envolvimento': envolvimento},
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }, "html");

    });
```

Para melhor compreensão aqui está a função do controller que faz a edição no banco:

```
function editarEnvolvido(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $rg = $_POST['rg'];
    $envolvimento = $_POST['envolvimento'];

    if((strcmp($id,"") != 0) && (strcmp($nome,"") != 0) && (strcmp($rg,"") != 0)){
        $data = array(
            'nome'                  => $nome,
            'rg'                    => $rg,
            'envolvimento'          => $envolvimento
        );
        if ($this->sbp_model->edit('envolvidos', $data, 'id', $id) == TRUE) {
            echo 'Salvo com sucesso!';
        } else {
            echo 'Erro ao tentar salvar!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Nome e/ou RG deve ser informado!';
    }
}
```

Gostaria de pelo menos entender o que está acontecendo que as demais linhas não dispara o ajax, e aceito sugestões adicionais para resolver meu problema. Agradecido desde já!

Comment: Quando vc disse que colocou cada form em um tr imagino que só tenha funcionado por causa que tenha usado o mesmo id no botão `#enviar` que deveria funcionar, muitas vezes pode ser erros assim, mesmo id para o formulário e tals

Comment: Entendi, você tem uma sugestão para eu solucionar este problema de edição de registro?

Comment: vc pode pegar o `$r->id` colocar como atributo no botão e no forma e fazer um serialize pegando pelo id. Estou meio corrido aqui, mas é por esse caminho, metade vc já tem ai

Comment: Valeu cara, vou tentar aqui! Agradecido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só pode atribuir um `id` para fazer o `bind` do `click`, por este motivo seu `ajax` só funciona no primeiro item, e como todos tem o mesmo `id` toda vez que você faz o envio, não importa qual linha edite, sempre vai pegar o primeiro que encontrar. Então vamos por partes:

**Ajustanto o HTML**

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    <input type="hidden" id="id_<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>" name="id_e" value="<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>">
    <input class="span9" type="text" id="nome_<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>" name="nome_e" value="<?php echo set_value('nome', $r->nome); ?>">
</td>
<td style="text-align: center">
    <input class="span6" id="rg_<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>" type="text" name="rg_e" value="<?php echo set_value('rg', $r->rg); ?>">
</td>
<td style="text-align: center">
    <select style="width: 120px" id="envolvimento_<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>" name="envolvimento_e" value="<?php echo set_value('envolvimento', $r->envolvimento); ?>">
        <option value="SOLICITANTE" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'SOLICITANTE') echo 'selected' ?>>
            Solicitante
        </option>
        <option value="AUTOR" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'AUTOR') echo 'selected' ?>>
            Autor
        </option>
        <option value="VITIMA" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'VITIMA') echo 'selected' ?>>
            Vítima
        </option>
        <option value="TESTEMUNHA" <?php if ($r->envolvimento == 'TESTEMUNHA') echo 'selected' ?>>
            Testemunha
        </option>
    </select>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center">
    <button type="button" onclick="enviar('<?php echo set_value('id', $r->id); ?>')" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Editar
    </button>
</td>
```

Repare que eu concatenei o `id` de cada registro para poder realmente ter um `ìd` único para cada linha. No botão, alterei para fazer uma chamada de uma `function` passando o `id` de qual linha deve ser editada.

**Editando o JS**

```
function enviar(row) {
    var id = $('#id_' + row).val();
    var nome = $('#nome_' + row).val();
    var rg = $('#rg_' + row).val();
    var envolvimento = $('#envolvimento_' + row).val();

    $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/sbp/editarEnvolvido",
        {'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'rg': rg, 'envolvimento': envolvimento},
        function (data) {
            alert(data);
    }, "html");
}
```

Nesta parte, basta concatenar o `id` novamente no seletor para trazer a informação correta da linha a ser editada.

Acho que isso já resolve tudo!